# Is there a way to improve performance of my View? (Actually using regexp_like)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where I have to use(or at least was the only solution I found) regexp_like on a big database(28k rows for now and will probably increase to 100k) but with this function it's taking too long.

Here is an exemple of what I'm trying to achieve:

TABLE_1:

```
**NUMBER**             **ANSWER**
100                      Answer 1
1100, 1099               Answer 2
99                       Answer 3
1099                     Answer 4
```

TABLE_2:

```
**NUMBER**   
100 
1100
1099    
99
```

I want to create a View where It compares Table 1 and 2 "NUMBER" column and return the "ANSWER" based on TABLE_2 "NUMBER". It would be return something like this:

View:

```
**NUMBER**             **ANSWER**
100                      Answer 1
1100                     Answer 2
1099                     Multiple Answer
99                       Answer 3
```

This is what I'm doing right now and it is taking forever:

```
SELECT A.*, (CASE
 WHEN (select count(distinct B.ANSWER) from TABLE_2 B WHERE regexp_like(B.NUMBER,'(^|\s|,)'||A.NUMBER||'(\s|$|,)'))> 1
 THEN 'Multiple Answer'
 ELSE (select count(distinct B.ANSWER) from TABLE_2 B WHERE regexp_like(B.NUMBER,'(^|\s|,)'||A.NUMBER||'(\s|$|,)'))
 END) FINAL_ANSWER

FROM Table_1 A
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need to fix your data structure.  Storing numbers as strings is wrong.  Storing multiple ids in a single field is wrong.  Not declaring foreign key constraints is bad.  Learn about junction tables.

Comment: 28k rows is not 'big', but running 28k `count(distinct)` without possible indexes is really bad...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I Know it's bad and I hate the person who did this but it's not my fault and I have to work my way around it...

Comment: @dnoeth I already indexed "ANSWERS" but it didn't work

Comment: It is FAR better to bring this up as a needed change right now to who ever owns the database. This is already causing performance issues at 28K which is, in database terms, teeny tiny. It will likely not work at all at 100K or higher. The data model is unsustainable and it will be much harder to fix the longer this goes on.  Is it possible to use a trigger to copy the data on entry to properly related tables so that you can effectively query if this table can't be changed?

Comment: @HLGEM I already asked them to change this on the next version. Hope they listen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to live with the unpleasant data model you have, here is an alternative to REGEXP_LIKE that you could try to see if it performs better:

```
select num
     , case when num_answers > 1 then 'multiple answer'
            else answer
            end final_answer
from (
select a.*
     , (select to_char(count(distinct b.answer))
          from table_1 b
         where ','||replace(b.num,' ','')||',' like '%,'||a.num||',%'
       ) num_answers
from table_2 a
);
```

The `replace` is to remove any spaces, then we check for e.g. ',1100,1099,' like '%,1099,%' - adding commas at both ends.

The use of a nested query avoids performing all the counts twice - you could adopt this approach with your REGEXP_LIKE version too.

Note:

1. I had to swap the tables round from your example
2. I had to rename your column NUMBER to NUM as NUMBER is a reserved word

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer!
Gonna try this to see how it works out!

Comment: I marked as correct because it works a lot faster now but the only problem  in your answer is that I can't use "else num_answer" because it will return the count(distinct b.answer) and not the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B."NUMBER",
       CASE MAX( A.ANSWER )
         WHEN MIN( A.ANSWER )
         THEN MAX( A.ANSWER )
         ELSE 'Multiple Answers'
         END AS Answer
FROM   TABLE_2 B
       INNER JOIN
       TABLE_1 A
       ON( REGEXP_LIKE( A."NUMBER", '(^|\D)' || B."NUMBER" || '(\D|$)' ) )
GROUP BY B."NUMBER";
```

Or, as @TonyAndrews suggests you could use string comparisons - either `LIKE` or:

```
FROM   TABLE_2 B
       INNER JOIN
       TABLE_1 A
       ON( INSTR( ','||REPLACE( A."NUMBER", ' ' )||',', ','||B."NUMBER"||',' ) > 0 )
```

Which you could potentially make faster by indexing `','||REPLACE( A."NUMBER", ' ' )||','` and `','||B."NUMBER"||','` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 ( "NUMBER", ANSWER ) AS
SELECT '100',        'Answer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1100, 1099', 'Answer 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '99',         'Answer 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1099',       'Answer 4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 ( "NUMBER" ) AS
SELECT 100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1099 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 99 FROM DUAL;

CREATE INDEX T1_WITH_NO_SPACES__IDX ON TABLE_1 (
    ','||REPLACE("NUMBER",' ')||',',
    ANSWER
);

CREATE INDEX T2_LIKE_WITH_COMMA__IDX ON TABLE_2 (
    '%,'||"NUMBER"||',%',
    "NUMBER"
);

SELECT B."NUMBER",
       CASE MAX( A.ANSWER )
         WHEN MIN( A.ANSWER )
         THEN MAX( A.ANSWER )
         ELSE 'Multiple Answers'
         END AS Answer
FROM   ( SELECT '%,'||"NUMBER"||',%' AS like_number,
                "NUMBER"
         FROM TABLE_2
       ) B
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT ','||REPLACE("NUMBER",' ')||',' AS numbers,
                ANSWER
         FROM TABLE_1
       ) A
       ON( numbers LIKE like_number )
GROUP BY B."NUMBER";
```

**Output**:

```
    NUMBER ANSWER         
---------- ----------------
       100 Answer 1         
      1099 Multiple Answers 
      1100 Answer 2         
        99 Answer 3
```

**Explain Plan**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                         |     8 |   440 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY         |                         |     8 |   440 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS         |                         |     8 |   440 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN     | T2_LIKE_WITH_COMMA__IDX |     4 |   148 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| T1_WITH_NO_SPACES__IDX  |     2 |    36 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter(','||REPLACE("NUMBER",' ')||',' LIKE '%,'||TO_CHAR("NUMBER")||',%')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how can I index ','||REPLACE( A."NUMBER", ' ' )||',' and ','||B."NUMBER"||','. ?

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso Updated with an example that should use index scans rather than table scans.